# Ways to store arbitrary data in a std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a third party api that provides the following type (approx.) for attaching arbitrary data to a node in a tree structure:

```
// 3rd party, cannot be modified
struct AttachedData
{
    std::string key;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
};
```

I think it uses `std::vector<unsigned char>` because the data could also be written to the disk, but this doesn't matter in my use case as the data only persists at runtime.

There are objects of different types that must be stored in `AttachedData` (only one object per instance). Since I need the data only at runtime I didn't bother implementing any type of serialization (mostly because of the unnecessary overhead). I decided to use a variant of all possible types and store a pointer to an instance thereof in `AttachedData`:

```
using StorageType = std::variant<EventArgs1, EventArgs2, SomeData /*, ...*/>;

AttachedData& attachedData = api.getAttachedData(targetNode, "some key"); // get the correct container
auto storage = new StorageType(someDataInstance); // somehow create the variant on the heap
attachedData.data.resize(sizeof(storage)); // make enough space
std::memcpy(attachedData.data.data(), &storage, sizeof(storage)); // store the pointer to the variant
```

On a different place in the code base the data is read and processed:

```
AttachedData& attachedData = api.getAttachedData(targetNode, "some key"); // get the correct container
StorageType* storage = nullptr;
std::memcpy(&storage, attachedData.data.data(), sizeof(storage)); // read the pointer

// process the stored data
if (auto* args1 = get_if<EventArgs1>(storage))
    // ...
else if (auto* args2 = get_if<EventArgs2>(storage))
    // ...
// ...

// clean up
attachedData.data.clear();
delete storage;
```

Is there a cleaner or more elegant way to do that? I also thought about using placement new and construct the variant directly in the vector but that would probably cause alignment issues and I don't see any benefits to it either. I think `std::variant` is a good way to go but I'm open to suggestions in that regard aswell.

Comment: If the data isn't persistent, why do you need `AttachedData` at all? After all, this just looks like a `std::map`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche 1. to associate them with a node in that tree structure. 2. It's possible that the `AttachedData` instance is moved by the third party api to a different node and I'm not always able to catch that. 3. (more of a con actually) it's possible that the node is deleted by the third party api. This would actually result in memory leak, but I think I'm able to catch that.

Comment: Does the third party API promise to not ever delete `AttachedData` itself (meaning your `delete` never happens), or copy it (potentially leading to double delete etc.)?

Comment: @FireLancer see point 3 of my last comment.

Comment: By "able to catch that", does it provide some events/hooks to copy/delete/etc.? Looks like you probably are best putting your data in a *trivially copyable* struct.

Comment: `Is there a cleaner or more elegant way to do that?` probably yes. Problem is that we do not know what this code suppose to do, your description says something about external API `AttachedData` without context what actually it does. This use of `memcopy` is undefined behavior (may work but doesn't have to). Storing pointer in `AttachedData` for me is a code smell, without context it is impossible what is wrong with it.

Comment: @MarekR why is it UB?

Comment: Storing pointer in something which suppose to be internalized/externalized will lead to UB for sure. If `AttachedData` is from third party library provide name of library.

Comment: What do you mean by `internalized/externalized`? I don't see how the library name would help here, it's a non-free library to support plugins for a specific software. I'm resizing the vector and storing the pointer to the actual data in the buffer (pointed to by `vector::data()`)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

*The approach proposed in this answer cannot work for OP, since, it turned out, that vectors stored in nodes may be copied, moved, or destructed with no user control. I won't delete the answer for now, since the discussion below clarifies some important details and may be useful for others.*

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I don't know whether I understood the problem well, but you can create an object of `StorageType` (i.e., `std::variant`) in the vector. You just need to resize the vector to fit the object inside:

```
AttachedData& attachedData = api.getAttachedData(targetNode, "some key");
attachedData.data.resize(sizeof(StorageType));
StorageType* p_obj = new (attachedData.data.data()) StorageType{someDataInstance};
```

Alignment should be fine as long as all variant's alternatives are not *over-aligned*.

Then, in the later code, you can obtain access to the stored object as follows:

```
AttachedData& attachedData = api.getAttachedData(targetNode, "some key"); // get the correct container
StorageType* p_obj = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<StorageType*>(attachedData.data.data()));
```

---

Note that you need to, somewhere, destruct all the stored objects manually by invoking destructor, or better with `std::destroy_at`.

---

As for you attempt, it has several problems. For instance, you cannot use `memcpy` for objects of *non-trivially-copyable* types, or you are using `&storage`, which is a pointer to a place in memory where `storage` pointer is stored (not a pointer where it points to).

**UPDATE**

According to your additional detail specified in comments, this approach won't work, since you don't control copies, moves, or destruction of vectors. In this case, no approach can generlly work. Once you create an object in the vector, its copy/move/destruction will not correctly involve copy/move/destruction of the object stored inside. Are your variant alternatives trivially-copyable?

Note that `std::variant` itself is not guaranteed to by *trivially-copyable* in C++17 even when all its alternatives are. There is a [proposal for this problem](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0602r4.html).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205605/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-langr-ways-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-a-stdvect).

Comment: @Timo I retract my claim that std::vector here is guaranteed to allocate suitably aligned storage for any non-overaligned type. I misread the relevant standard passage. It only says that `std::allocator` *uses* `::operator new` to allocate storage and returns storage suitably aligned for the element type.